# Using article frontmatter when iterating in Middleman blog

Tags: css, ruby, middleman

Not the best title, but I'm honestly not sure on how to properly explain what I'm looking for help for.

So I'm using Middleman blog to well create my blog. Anyways, I'm using frontmatter to pass css that change the look of each page individually. I'm using 4 variables, link_color, text_color, bg_link. So what I want to do is reuse that same frontmatter information in the layout.html.erb file.

So the layout.html.erb is the standard

```
<% if paginate && num_pages > 1 %>
    <p>Page <%= page_number %> of <%= num_pages %></p>

    <% if prev_page %>
      <p><%= link_to 'Previous page', prev_page %></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <% page_articles.each_with_index do |article, i| %>
    <li class="article_summary">
        <h1><%= link_to article.title, article, id: "#{i}" %></h1>
    </li>
  <% end %>

  <% if paginate %>
    <% if next_page %>
      <p><%= link_to 'Next page', next_page %></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

What I'm trying to do is for each article within that iterator is if the article has `bg_color` frontmatter then use that and change the color of the `article.title` if not, then do nothing. Currently if I try with something like:

```
<style>
<% if article.data.bg_color? %>
  .article_summary a#<%= i %>{
    color: rgb(<%=article.data.bg_color %>);
  }
  <% end %>
</style>
```

I'm doing it this way because my blog lives on Github.

Currently it works, but since it's just a simple iteration it gives every article that same color and not on a per article basis. So I'm trying to figure out the best way to utilize the index as some sort of id so that they're targeted individually.

Perhaps changing the li from a class to an id consisting of the index, but then I won't be able to apply a global style from the scss in the stylesheet folder no?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a dirty method that works.

```
<% page_articles.each_with_index do |article, i| %>
    <li class="article_summary" id="test_<%=i %>">
        <h1><%= link_to article.title, article %></h1>
        <style>
          <% if article.data.bg_color? %>
              #test_<%=i%> a{
              color: <%=article.data.bg_color %>;
            }
          <% end %>
      </style>
    </li>
  <% end %>
```

Pretty much added "test_" to the id (before I was just doing the index itself) and viola!